# NSOperation key-value observing isExecuting old and new values not as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, nsoperation

When observing the `isExecuted` property on an `NSOperation` object, I am seeing some unexpected behavior.  I register an observer with the `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` and `NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld` options.  I would expect the last observation change dictionary for `isExecuting` to have the value `@YES` for the `NSKeyValueChangeNewKey` and `@NO` for the `NSKeyValueChangeOldKey`.  However, I am seeing those values swapped.  All other observations occur as expected.  Am I doing something wrong or is there possibly a bug in the SDK?  I am using Xcode 8 with iOS SDK version 10.0, and my project target platform is 8.0.

The following is a failing XCTestCase to illustrate the unexpected behavior I'm seeing.

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface TestNSOperationKVO : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation TestNSOperationKVO {
    NSMutableArray<NSDictionary *> *changes;
}

NSString *kKeyPath = @"keyPath";
NSString *kChange = @"change";

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    changes = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testIsExecutingKVO {
    NSOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{}];
    [op addObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(isExecuting)) options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
    [op addObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(isFinished)) options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];

    [op start];

    XCTAssertEqual(changes.count, 3);
    XCTAssert([@"isExecuting" isEqualToString:changes[0][kKeyPath]]);
    XCTAssertEqual(changes[0][kChange][NSKeyValueChangeOldKey], @NO);
    XCTAssertEqual(changes[0][kChange][NSKeyValueChangeNewKey], @YES);
    XCTAssert([@"isExecuting" isEqualToString:changes[1][kKeyPath]]);
    // this fails
    XCTAssertEqual(changes[1][kChange][NSKeyValueChangeOldKey], @YES);
    // this fails
    XCTAssertEqual(changes[1][kChange][NSKeyValueChangeNewKey], @NO);
    XCTAssert([@"isFinished" isEqualToString:changes[2][kKeyPath]]);
    XCTAssertEqual(changes[2][kChange][NSKeyValueChangeOldKey], @NO);
    XCTAssertEqual(changes[2][kChange][NSKeyValueChangeNewKey], @YES);
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context
{
    [changes addObject:@{kKeyPath: keyPath, kChange: change}];
}

@end
```